# Ruby on rails warning "ruby is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-big-sur

When i run rails commands on the terminal like creating a model, this is the error I get:

`WARNING: /Users/my_mac_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way`

`[1]    5396 abort      bin/rails g model ModelName attribute_1:string attribute_2:integer`

My mac is running big sur,

Answer (score 8):

I ended up solving the same issue using information from this thread: https://giters.com/se3000/ruby-eth/issues/47

The solution which worked out of the box for me, on an M1 Mac, was to use the following:

```
sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/libssl.dylib  /usr/local/lib
```

This is definitely a dylib issue, as @tbraden pointed out.

Comment: Above works, but be mindful of which version of openssl you have/need on your system. `brew --prefix openssl` will return the most recent version (openssl@3), however some folks (such as myself) are using openssl@1.1.

In those cases, it should be `$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)`.

Comment: Didn't help me :(

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning not a fatal error. On mac you can open the `Console` program (spotlight search `Console`) and look for the ruby crash log.

For me it is error on invalid dylib load, which can be solved by creating the symlink following this thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119429.

Answer (score 1):

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70745203/5347939) will work if you have latest version of libssl

However if you have `1.1` version, you need to run the following

```
sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/libssl.dylib  /usr/local/lib
```

Also before running any command you can verify to which version it points on current moment

```
ls -la /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  46 Mar  3 14:27 /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib -> /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib

ls -la /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  43 Mar  3 14:27 /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib -> /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error awhile ago working on a Ruby 2.7.5/Rails 6.0 app. I was able to fix it with symlinking the libcryto and libssl files as stated above.

However I started to encounter this problem again recently. I discovered it was an issue with an older version of the `eth` gem which was a dependency of the `magic-auth` gem in my app. Details are in [this Github issue](https://github.com/se3000/ruby-eth/issues/47).

To resolve, I upgraded the gem to version 0.14 (or whatever the latest version at the time of this post). So far, the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

*For Macbook with Intel Chip the solution is to update eth gem.*

Comment: This was already suggested by @johnpitchko.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.